# Installing pyOpt on python in ubuntu

Tags: python, pycharm

I have downloaded pyOpt from its website and installed it on python in ubuntu, using the instructions on the website.

Still, I cannot import and use it in my pycharm projects.

Comment: Open a new terminal, run python, can you import it there? If so, ensure your python version matches what pycharm is running, and that you have restarted pycharm.

Comment: They actually do match pyOpt is basically written for python 2 and my interpreter is python 2.7 in pycharm. I cannot import it in Pycharm even though I did it using terminal.

Comment: You are likely running two separate python binaries, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#local-interpreter and make sure your pycharm is setup to use the same python binary that runs when you run python in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I did not dare to try Akin's solution for my research project (I think it is a good solution if anyone wants to stick to PyOpt package with python3).

I used Pyomo instead.

By the way, Laurent's answer actually points to another package. PyOpt and pyopt are two different packages.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to figure this out too. It seems that the code for the pyOpt package is written in **Python 2**; when attempting to import anything once all system requirements have been met, the errors I received all point towards this. I will update this answer once I have figured out a way round this.

It should be feasible to simply have the script code converted to python 3 but I have not do this before.

**Edit**
You can use the package **2to3** to convert all the scripts to be compatible with Python 3.

Navigate to the correct folder through the command line in which the pyOpt files are.

Then use `2to3[pyOpt-1.2.0]-w`and this will rewrite all the scripts to be compatible with Python 3.  Note that you don't need the [] in the command. See 1 for further details.
[1](https://medium.com/@ankurshva/convert-python2-code-to-python3-with-one-line-of-code-4aec138899a3)
Then you should be able to run `python setup.py install` and all should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

[`PyOpt`](https://pypi.org/project/pyopt/) correctly works with Python 3. I have tried with Python 3.6.

I recommend you to use a virtualenv. You can consult the [user guide](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/) online.

For instance, you can do:

```sh
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install pyopt
```

If  you use [pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew), you can do:

```sh
pew new -p python3.6  pyOpt -i pyOpt
```

This will create a new virtualenv for you and install pyopt.

To test pyopt, you can follow the documentation. You can try:

```py
>>> import pyopt
>>> expose = pyopt.Exposer()
>>> @expose.args
... def regular_function(arg1:str, arg2:int):
...     """Your help - the docstring"""
...     print(repr(arg1), repr(arg2))
... 
>>> expose.run()
Usage:  arg1 arg2
```

To work with PyCharm, you can consult the article [“Virtual environment”](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html).

In short: Open the **Preferences** and search **Add Python Interpreter**. Clic on **And Interpreter...** and select **Existing environment**. That way, you can select the `python` executable which is in `.env/bin` directory.

IMHO you should use [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) instead of PyOpt, really.